# Create lines in windows form with visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I wonder if it's possible to add a line to the design in a windows form? I can't find any tool for this in the toolbox? Or is there some other way to do this in visual studio or in code?

Comment: Horizontal line? Like the <HR /> HTML tag?

Comment: see [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/0d4b986e-3ed0-4933-a15d-4b42e02005a7/) link

Comment: possible duplicate of [Draw horizontal divider in winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296110/draw-horizontal-divider-in-winforms)  Also the answer there by Dave76 is excellent, since you can use it in the form designer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3296161/353094

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't a built-in control for WinForms to do this. You can use the `GroupBox` control though, set the `Text` property to an empty string, and set it's height to `2`. This will mimic a embossed line. Otherwise, you need to create a custom control and paint the line yourself.

For a custom control, here's an example.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication12
{
    public partial class Line : Control
    {
        public Line() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }        

        private Color m_LineColor = Color.Black;
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the color of the divider line
        /// </summary>
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [Description("Gets or sets the color of the divider line")]
        public Color LineColor {
            get {
                return m_LineColor;
            }
            set {
                m_LineColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe) {
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(LineColor)) {
                pe.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, pe.ClipRectangle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It simply fills the `ClientRectangle` with the specified `LineColor`, so the height and width of the line is that of the control itself. Adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void DrawLShapeLine(System.Drawing.Graphics g, int intMarginLeft, int intMarginTop, int intWidth, int intHeight) 
    { 
        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black); 
        myPen.Width = 2; 
        // Create array of points that define lines to draw. 
        int marginleft = intMarginLeft; 
        int marginTop = intMarginTop; 
        int width = intWidth; 
        int height = intHeight; 
        int arrowSize = 3; 
        Point[] points = 
         { 
            new Point(marginleft, marginTop), 
            new Point(marginleft, height + marginTop), 
            new Point(marginleft + width, marginTop + height), 
            // Arrow 
            new Point(marginleft + width - arrowSize, marginTop + height - arrowSize), 
            new Point(marginleft + width - arrowSize, marginTop + height + arrowSize), 
            new Point(marginleft + width, marginTop + height) 
         }; 

        g.DrawLines(myPen, points); 
    } 
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) 
{ 
   DrawLShapeLine(e.Graphics, 10, 10, 20, 40); 
}
```

See the following link for more
[Drawing a line in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078137/drawing-a-line-in-winforms)

Comment: Answers containing just a link are not very useful.

Comment: @svick Agree with you, Updated.