# ListBox Dividing Line .NET Windows Forms

Tags: .net, winforms, listbox

In .NET Windows forms, is there an easy way to add a horizontal dividing line?  It should be non-selectable.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391441/adding-line-to-asp-net-to-listbox), I believe, talks about the same thing in ASP.NET.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078137/drawing-a-line-in-winforms

Comment: Use the ListBox.DrawItem event.